# Run XAgent using scheduled LotusScript or Java agent

Tags: xpages

Since there is no such thing as a scheduled server-side javascript agent, I want to use a scheduled LotusScript or Java agent to periodically call a XAgent, i.e. call the XAgent's url. In LotusScript, the code of the agent (initialize) looks like this:

```
Dim w As New NotesUIWorkspace
w.Urlopen "http://domain/db.nsf/XAgent.xsp"
```

When I directly call the XAgent's url (in the browser), it is executed succesfully. Yet, the XAgent is not executed when I call it using the agent above. Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong and/or provide another solution, like for example a Java agent?

Comment: Does the LotusScript open a browser window in your case? If it does then I don't see any problem with XAgent not executing. It does execute in my case.

Comment: No, the agent does not open a browser window. Even if I execute the agent in server-side javascript with database.getAgent("agent").run().

Comment: You must take into account your server configuration. If you call your XAgent url, you will possibly get login page response instead of requested xsp.

Comment: This is strange, the code `workspace.Urlopen` should open the URL in browser window. Go to "File > Preferences" and select "Web Browser". What does it show there? You can configure which browser should be opened from clicking hyperlink on Notes client. Also the code `database.getAgent("agent").run()` will run an _actual_ agent. XAgent is **not** an agent. It's [a term coined by Stephan H Wissel](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/shwl-7mgfbn).

Comment: NotesUIWorkspace is not available in scheduled agents. The key indication of this is the "UI" portion of the class name. ;)

Comment: If @TimTripcony is right then your code will not work. I thought you were calling the code on click of a button or action hotspot.

Comment: Tim Tripcony is completely right: The agent cannot work that way using Notes **UI** Workspace. Hence, I'm now using a Java agent with java.net.URL to establish a url connection (as suggested by Egor Margineanu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go for Java agent, you can always use java.net.* classes to open an URL, or use Apache HTTP client library.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wrote a Java agent that makes use of java.net.URL and it works fine now. Even though your answer helped me solve the problem and even though I'm not using Mark Leusink's solution, I accepted Panu Haaramo's answer because the provided link will perfectly help people having the same issue. I hope you don't mind.